# How to change Labels text in kivy from another class in python?

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language

How can I change the text of Label in LessonWindow class from LessonList class ?

When I press to any Button in LessonsList class the text of the label has to be the number of the Button.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
kv = Builder.load_file('test.kv')


class LessonsList(Screen):
    def press(self):
        manager.current = "lesson"


class LessonWindow(Screen):
    def back(self):
        manager.current = "lessons"
        manager.transition.direction = "left"


manager = ScreenManager()
manager.add_widget(LessonsList(name="lessons"))
manager.add_widget(LessonWindow(name="lesson"))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

here is my kv file:

```
<LessonsList>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Lesson 1'
            on_press: root.press()
        Button:
            text:'Lesson 2'
            on_press:root.press()
        Button:
            text:'Lesson 3'
            on_press: root.press()

<LessonWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Lesson'
        Button:
            text:'Back'
            on_press: root.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` for that `Label` in your `kv`:

```
<LessonWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: lab  # added id
            text: 'Lesson'
        Button:
            text:'Back'
            on_press: root.back()
```

Then you can use that `id` in your `press()` method:

```
def press(self):
    manager.current = "lesson"
    lesson_window = self.manager.get_screen('lesson')
    label = lesson_window.ids.lab
    label.text = 'Changed Text'
```